# How to upgrade storyboard if pressed "SKIP" on previous "Upgrade?"

Tags: xcode5

Opening old project (ios6, xcode4) in Xcode5 I accidentally pressed "SKIP" when was asked about storyboards upgrade.
 I closed the project and reopened it - no any upgrade questions anymore...

How can I upgrade storyboards now to Xcode5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can revert or redo this storyboard upgrades on the file inspector of the storyboard (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>). In the section **Interface Builder Document** use the setting for **"Opens in"**.

- To perform a skipped upgrade: set to **Xcode 5.0** (or Default)
- To undo an upgrade: set to **Xcode 4.6**

[image]

If this helps, please mark question solved.